# When ICO doesn't take place?

Tags: ico

If company that produce ICO want to get N money, but the company did not collect as much of necessary amount of money. Is it means that ICO did not take place and company will not launch?

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the company and how they make their contracts for token distribution. If some have a minimum investment goal, ideally they would code in their smart contracts to refund all of funds they received if they did not receive their goal by a certain date. If they are transparent about their smart contracts, this will build confidence that they are out to produce a legitimate product/service.

Say a company does this, and launches their token ICO. If they don't reach their target, they could just go back to the drawing board, revise their business plan, and re-launch. This may seem like they are a failure because they couldn't raise that the first time. But I think instead this will be a better way to prove that their product/service is more deserving of whatever funds they receive.